# EF6 Entity framework sometimes slow query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

We have started a new project in .NET Core.  We are just starting out and we are hitting a Web API endpoint to get some reference data of 8 records.

We noticed in our Angular screen that perodically (about every 10 requests) to a screen that the EF query takes about 6  to 15 seconds to run, rather than the 30ms it normally takes.

On debugging we know that we are getting right up to the `.ToListAsync()` and then in SQL profiler we can see it initiates the query and it take a delayed time.

So first impressions says its a SQL issue but if we run the SQL query manually in SQL itself it never delays.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have to do with the connection pooling setup of efcore, It should not request a new connection on each request to db, enable connection pooling by adding this in your dependency management:

```
builder.Services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<DbContext>(
o => o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppContext")));
```

reference :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant